# Tkinter Filtered Listbox won't update

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to make a Filtered Listbox activated by a button, by itself the Lists box works fine but when I indent it inside a function the Filtering feature stop to work, find the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
a = ['Adam', 'Lucy', 'Barry', 'Bob']
def bot(*args):
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    def update_listbox(*args):
        search_term = search_var.get()
        listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
        for item in all_items:
            if search_term.lower() in item.lower():
                listbox.insert(tk.END, item)
        

    search_var = tk.StringVar()
    search_var.trace('w', update_listbox)
    searchbox = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=search_var)
    searchbox.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=False)

    listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
    for i in a:
        listbox.insert(tk.END, i)        
    listbox.pack()
    all_items = listbox.get(0, tk.END)
    root.mainloop()

RootTest = tk.Tk()
bott = tk.Button(RootTest, text = 'test', )
bott.pack()
bott.config(command= bot)
RootTest.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello! I recommend adding a snippet of code that does work, and then explaining the changes you made that caused your code to stop working.

Comment: You are having multiple instance of `Tk()` and that could be the problem, either try replacing child windows with `Toplevel()` or `search_var=tk.StringVar(master=root)`.

Comment: You are a boss Cool Cloud 'search_var=tk.StringVar(master=root)' worked perfectly thanks a lot.